# Can I reinstall macOS on my Mac after it's been turned into a Linux box?

Tags: macos, install, unix

I inherited a Mac Pro Tower with CentOS on it. I want to reinstall macOS on it using an external CD/DVD drive that's plugged into a USB port.

I have tried holding down the C-key on startup.
I have tried resetting NVRAM.

Any suggestions on how to get some kind of Mac prompt? I know zero about Linux.

Comment: What year **Mac Pro** is it? What version of the OS do you have on DVD? Most non-servers versions that came on DVD are tied to specific models of hardware.

Comment: I have a version of Snow Leopard on DVD. It's a 2008 Tower.

Comment: Is the CD a retail one [picture of a cat] or one supplied with a new Mac [grey]? Retail should work, grey is less likely, as it may be very model-specific.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I reinstall macOS on my Mac after it's been turned into a Linux box?

Of course you can, there's no Mac (or any computer for that matter) that has been irreparably limited to never running it's native operating system ever again.

Yes, you can "brick" things but that's usually a firmware issue or in Apple's case, a security "thing" that you couldn't either unlock the firmware or the FileVault encryption.

> I have tried holding down the C-key on startup. I have tried resetting NVRAM.

- Holding the <kbd>C</kbd> key tells the Mac to boot from the CD/DVD drive.  Did you have an install disk loaded?  If not, it's not going to do anything
- The NVRAM is your pre-boot environment that sets things like which partition is your startup volume or what the screen resolution *at boot* should be.  Resetting your SMC/NVRAM is Internet folklore that it somehow fixes things when in reality, in 99.99% of the cases, it's not related to the problem at all.

The 2008 Mac Pro originally came with Leopard (10.5.x) but can run El Capitan (10.11.x).   The best way to get this installed would be to get ahold of an El Capitan USB Installer and install it that way...

- have a friend with a Mac download and create the installer for you
- take it to an Apple store and they will assist with the installation

When you get the installer created, simply put it into a USB slot, and hold the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key while booting.  This will take you into the boot manager where you can select the USB drive as the boot volume.

Comment: I have plugged in an El Capitan USB installer and booted with the Option key pressed. It still boots up in CentOs. (I have proven the efficacy of the USB by using it to install El Capitan on another machine).

Comment: (Sorry... the grammar police showed up). Then, it's the keyboard's *efficacy* that's in question.  I don't have any doubts as to the USB's *viability* (the word I believe you were looking for) as it worked in another machine.  *Efficacy* deals with the *ability* to produce a result where viability refers to it's *success.*  Holding `Opt` should bring you into a boot manager and list all of the bootable partitions, even if just one.  The fact that you're immediately going into Cent-OS tells me it's not seeing the keypress.  Try a USB keyboard, even if a PC-101; hold the `Alt` key.

Comment: Thanks for policing my grammar. I need that sometimes. So, update: 
- New keyboard with Option pressed on startup
- I see the Mac options for which drive to boot from, so that's good.
- Then I go to select my boot USB but it's frozen (can't select USB and press Enter)
- It then proceeds to boot up Centos again.

Comment: We're getting somewhere!  That boot manager, you now see the USB drive and the CentOS drive, but you're saying "it's frozen."  You can't select it at all?  Can you use the mouse to click on it?

Comment: I see two drives: 1. The internal drive called "Windows" (not sure if that helps), and 2. the USB El Capitan boot drive. Using the arrow keys I am able to navigate over to the USB boot drive before it freezes (can't navigate back to the "Windows" drive or press enter to set anything in motion). I have experimented with trying to tap Enter on the Windows drive, or very quickly selecting the USB option and hitting enter. I'm not having any luck.

Comment: It's "Windows" because CentOS was probably installed on an MBR partition scheme.  The fact that you see the USB drive means it read the EFI partition on it and "knows" you can boot from it.  However, it "freezing" while still in the boot manager is concerning.  This is one of the rare times I'll recommend resetting the NVRAM, but give that a shot.  Also, try disconnecting the internal drive and booting the USB just to see if that has any effect.

Comment: I may be dealing with some deeper issues. I've swapped out the hard drive and attempted to boot from the USB (now shows just the USB as an option). The cursor is there, but moving the mouse doesn't move the cursor.

Comment: I think that particularMac  came with mountain lion. Do you have the install disks?  If you can install macOS via DVD maybe you can do a firmware update/reinstall.

Comment: If only. This box has no optical drive. I may end up using this as a boat anchor.

Comment: Do you have another Mac and another drive?  If you can do a clean install of El Cap on the other drive (even via USB). See if it’ll boot then. If you can’t, message me.  We’ll figure it out

Comment: Are you talking about installing the OS on an external drive and then slotting it into the Mac Pro box after?

Comment: Exactly. This way it has nothing but macOS to boot to

Comment: I think this has some unresolvable issues. I installed the OS onto the drive and tried to boot up from that disc. I held down the Option key and saw the choice of drives to boot from. At this point, it froze like it did before. I'm not going to pursue this any further. I think I have a boat anchor.